# Iterate through a character array while skipping over whitespace

Tags: c, arrays, string, character

I'm trying to write a program that iterates through a character array (which contains a sentence), and assigns the words in that sentence to another array, skipping over spaces (which is how we know separate words), and then prints those words.

Say for example my character array is:

```
{'t','h','e',' ','f','o','x',' ','r','u','n','s','\0',}
```

I want my function to assign the words to an array, call it `words`, one at a time, skipping over the spaces, the words then printed one by one.

I tried this:

```
for (i = 0, x = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++, x++){
    if (a[i] != ' '){
        words[x] = a[i];
    }
    else{
        words[x] = '\0';
            printf("%s\n", words);
            x=0;
            i++;
            continue;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", words);
```

But when I ran it, it only printed out `s`

Comment: Where are you defining and setting temp_var?  Because temp_var is what you're printing and it's not set in the code you're running.

Comment: @Allaboutthatbase2 fixed it, was incorrect variable name

Comment: You have an index `j` that is not used. You are using an index `x` but there is nothing that changes it. Problem of transcribing code?

Comment: I added a working example. You need to add additional subscripting to words, and make it a multi-dimensional array. That's one approach.  Or you'd need a more complex solution with malloc and pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the variables (except for the array `a`, which is explicitly set to a string) defined outside of main are zeroed by default by the compiler and don't need to be explicitly initialized, but you must be very careful about initialization in general and especially within functions.

And `a`, though defined as a pointer to a string literal can also be accessed as an array of characters.

Output:

```
words[0] = the
words[1] = fox
words[2] = runs
```

This works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_WORDS 1000
#define MAX_WORD_LEN 32
char *a = "the fox runs";
char words[MAX_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LEN];
int i, j, k;

int
main(void) 
{
    for (i = 0; k < MAX_WORDS && a[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (a[i] != ' ' && j <= 32) {
            words[k][j++] = a[i];
        } else {
            words[k++][j] = '\0';
            printf("words[%d] = %s\n", k - 1, words[k - 1]);
            j = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("words[%d] = %s\n", k, words[k]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion, go with [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok). It'll be much easy.

The idea:

1. Use `strtok()` and space `' '` as delimiter to find out each occurrence of *words*.
2. use `strcpy()` to copy to copy the returned `token`s (*words*) to the `word` array.

Note:

> I want my function to assign the words to an array, call it words, one at a time, skipping over the spaces, the words then printed one by one.

Your current code does not look like it's doing the same.

1. You can get rid of the `for` loop iteraing over the input string.
2. You need to contuinue the `strtok()` on the same input untill it rerturns `NULL`.
3. `words[x]` needs to be  a `char *` (with properly allocated memory) or `char []` (array) to hold each *word* found from the input string and later to print one by one.

Answer (score 0):

With continue in for loop you don't need to have `i++` and you need to set `x=-1`.

```
for (i = 0, j = 0; a[i] != '\0'; i++, x++){
    if (a[i] != ' '){
        words[x] = a[i]; // U need to use j
    }
    else{
        words[x] = '\0';
             printf("%s\n", words);
            x=-1; // as you are using continue
            // i++; You don't need this
            continue;
        }
    }
     printf("%s\n", words);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the full program?

```
words[x] = a[i];
```

You would probably want to put `words[x]` in a loop incrementing `x` by `1` everytime you don' t find a whitespace.

Ok I noticied you have edited it. Also, its an array so I suppose you need to loop through the array and print each character.

For printing,

```
for (j = 0; j < sizeof(words)/sizeof(words[0]); j++ )
    {
        printf("%c", words[j] );
    }
```